# Encode an image from a URL to Base64 without a canvas

Tags: javascript

I need to encode an image from a url as base64. I originally tried using a canvas:

```
function convertImgToBase64(url, callback, outputFormat) {
    console.log('converting image to base 64');
    var canvas = document.createElement('CANVAS');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var img = new Image;
    img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
    console.log('have image context');
    img.onload = function() {
        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL(outputFormat || 'image/png');
        console.log('data url: ' + dataURL);
        callback.call(this, dataURL);
        // Clean up
        canvas = null;
    };
    img.src = url;
}
```

But `img.onload` never gets called. This didn't surprise me because I'm working solely in javascript without an HTML page. I essentially need to replicate the functionality from this site:

http://www.freeformatter.com/base64-encoder.html

I've tried reverse engineering the site, but I haven't been able to figure out how they're encoding my input URL as base64. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A canvas doesn't hold (for example) a jpg. A jpg is lossy. When you load it into canvas, it gets 'unpacked'. When you use a built-in canvas method to output a dataURL, it will *first* re-compress the raw canvas-data (32 bit per pixel inc alpha) to the (lossy-level depending on internal paramaters) format you have chosen as output, *then* convert that data to base64.

What I'm trying to say here is, that canvas would not produce a true base64 encoding of the *original* file; instead it would produce a base64 encoding of the canvas-content (one of canvas' supported output formats). In yet other words: you are not base64-encoding the original binary.

That being said and explained.. there is more.. you might stumble on cross-site security problems inside the *browser* (assuming you want to be able to feed *any* URL).

Thus the solution, solving *both problems above* (also employed by the website you referenced), is to pass the URL (or the bare text entered or file uploaded) to the server where the server gets the image (data) and base64 encodes it (the actual *original* binary) and passes it back to the client(browser) (for example via AJAX/JSON/etc.).

However, you also say that you are "working solely in javascript without an HTML page". That's kind of vague. In my answer above I assumed a browser (as host) anyway (otherwise you would have mentioned node.js (or something like that) and you'd have gotten error messages about `document`). If however you do use node, then there is probably something available to download the binary contents from an URL (which you then pass through your javascript implementation of base64 (which again is probably already available in node.js)).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I ended up writing a php script that handles the encoding

Comment: You are welcome, good on you for doing the php solution! (vastly more simple and dodging cross-site stuff).

Answer (score 0):

The site at most likely use serverside technology (ASP, PHP, etc) to download the image and get it's base64 encoding. You cannot reverse engineer something that is executed on the serverside.

If you use clientside technology (like JavaScript) you may run into "Cross-Origin Resource Sharing"-problems.

The code you have supplied works as it should and you can see this by executing the following 2 calls.
Please note that Wikipedia allows resource sharing while jshell.net (JSFiddle) does not - so check you **console log** for the "Cross-Origin Resource Sharing"-error message.

```
// Works fine:
convertImgToBase64("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4a/Logo_2013_Google.png", function(data){alert(data)});

// Does not work due to "Cross-Origin Resource Sharing"
convertImgToBase64("http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png", function(data){alert(data)});
```